# Phonegap: display list of photos in camera roll?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I want to create a multi photo upload for my phonegap app -- currently this is not available so I'm wondering if it would be possible to create an HTML version of the camera roll.

My thought would be if I could get access to the list of photo URI's from the camera roll, I'd display them in my own HTML version of the camera roll, allow multiple photos to be selected, and then upload the ones that are selected - bypassing the native camera roll.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because iOS apps are sandboxed:

> For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

*(Source: [Apple's iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html))*

This means that an app can only access its own files directly. So the photo roll is the only way for you to access the photos stored on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'm assuming that means the only way I'd be able to allow multiple photo selection from the camera roll is to create a plug in?