# Retrive list of photos in a Camera Roll using Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Using Phonegap and the [Camera Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/af18483d6970b32a22f016292d3d2cb921eedb00/doc/index.md) - is it possible to retrieve the list of photos in the camera roll.

Ultimately I want to be able to add the list of photos into an array so a random photo can be selected.

I'd need this to work in iOS and Android.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404296/phonegap-display-list-of-photos-in-camera-roll) but without an answer.

Comment: that SO Post is with answer. he said *"This is not possible because iOS apps are sandboxed:"*

Comment: Yes but that was asked in 2012.

Comment: Do you think that apple changed their security policys? Apps still run in sandboxes, it's only more sand inside them then in 2012.

Comment: Ok, im not too knowledgeable with sandboxes, does it basically mean that my app cant access details of the cameraroll app?

Comment: Also - the CameraRoll app isn't sandboxed.